# WinAPI C++ GDI черный экран через некоторое время работы

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, gdi

Программа работает некоторое время корректно, но потом без видимых причин просто превращает кадр в черный квадрат. Грешил на переполнение стэка, но поиски не увенчались успехом

```
void Paint(PAINTSTRUCT &ps) // Отрисовка
{
    HDC hMemDC, hTempDC; // Теневой буффер
    HGDIOBJ hMemBmp, hSysBmp;
    hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ps.hdc); // Создать конекст схожии с основным
    hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(ps.hdc, sizeX, sizeY);
    hSysBmp = SelectObject(hMemDC, hMemBmp);
    SetViewportOrgEx(hMemDC, sizeX / 2, sizeY / 2, nullptr);
    // Отрисовка фона
    hTempDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ps.hdc);
    SelectObject(hTempDC, BGround);
    BitBlt(hMemDC, -sizeX / 2, -sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY, hTempDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hTempDC, hSysBmp);
    DeleteDC(hTempDC);

    // Отрисовка наполнения
    for (UINT i = 0; i < PlanetOrigin.size(); i++)
        PlanetOrigin[i].Draw(hMemDC);
    SunOrigin->Draw(hMemDC);
    if (RESET)
        for (UINT i = 0; i < KometOrigin.size(); i++)
            KometOrigin[i].Draw(hMemDC);
    PaintButtons(hMemDC); // Отрисовка кнопок
    BitBlt(ps.hdc, 0, 0, sizeX, sizeY, hMemDC, -sizeX / 2, -sizeY / 2, SRCCOPY); // Отправка в основной контекст
    SelectObject(hMemDC, hSysBmp);
    DeleteObject(hMemBmp); // Удаление Битмапа
    DeleteDC(hMemDC); // Удаление контекстов
    if (GAME) // ИГра?
        Mathematic(); // Расчеты
}
```

Есть еще обработка колесика мышки, которая изменяет размеры bitmap  в реальном времени

```
if (GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam) > 0) // Если движение вверх
            {
                if (SIZABLE >= 10) // Не превышает ли допустимого значения
                    break;
                SIZABLE++;
                for (UINT i = 0; i < PlanetOrigin.size(); i++) // Для планет
                {
                    PlanetOrigin[i].Resize(true);
                    PlanetOrigin[i].ResizeOrbit(true);
                }
                SunOrigin->Resize(true); // Для солнца
                for (UINT i = 0; i < KometOrigin.size(); i++) // Для комет
                {
                    KometOrigin[i].Resize(true);
                    KometOrigin[i].ResizeCoord(true);
                }
            }

void ObjectGalaxy::Resize(bool direction) // Изменение размеров (перерасчеты в основном)
{

    size = (direction ? size*sZoom : size / sZoom); // Новый размер
    gravity_rad = (direction ? gravity_rad*sZoom : gravity_rad / sZoom); // Новый радиус гравитации
    gravity_f = (direction ? gravity_f*sZoom : gravity_f / sZoom); // Новая сила гравитации
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)CopyImage(hOrigin, IMAGE_BITMAP, (int)size, (int)size, LR_COPYRETURNORG); // Из оригинального изображения делаем итоговое через сжатие
    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap); // Для получения реальной информации о битмапе
}
```

Отрисовка для всех объектов, кроме фона:

```
void ObjectGalaxy::DrawObject(HDC hdc)
{
    if (this->GetDrawChance())
        return;
    HDC hMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // Соотнесение с полученным контекстом
    HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hMem, hBitmap); // Двойная буферизация
    TransparentBlt(hdc, (int)position.first - bitmap.bmWidth / 2, (int)position.second - bitmap.bmHeight / 2, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hMem, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, RGB(0, 0, 0)); // Копирование с пропуском белого
    SelectObject(hMem, hOld);
    DeleteDC(hMem); // Удаление контекста
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге изображение заменяется на черный прямоугольник

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, так как не знаю WinApi, но есть функции перерисовки. Сама операционная система может сама по себе перерисовывать ваше окошко. Оттуда мы и получаем черное окошко.  Даже изменение размера окна заставляет окно перерисовываться.

Comment: Нет проверок возвращаемых значений. Если хочется буферизированной отрисовки лучше использовать `BeginBufferedPaint`. В строке `SelectObject(hTempDC, hSysBmp);` ошибка - `hSysBmp` до этого был выбран в контекст `hMemDC`.

Comment: "черный экран через некоторое время работы" -- первым делом, проверьте программу на утечки GDI-ресурсов ([GDI Leaks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, проблема, как заметил mega, оказалась в утечке GDI-объектов. Советую использовать программу типа GDIVIEW для отслеживания ресурсов (ведет она себя, конечно, странно, но серьезные утечки продемонстрирует сразу)